# How to set Alarm in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Following is my code can Any body please tell me why it is not working .I have learned it from  [this tutorial](http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=alarmreceiver-excellent-tutorial).  But it is not working any help will be appreciable.

My code is

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Notify extends Activity {
    Button btn;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.nit);
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,6);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2011);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,29);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,17);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);

        //String[] dude=new String[] {"nitin","avi","aman","rahul","pattrick","minkle","manmohan","nitin","nitin"};

        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,dude));
        //getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        //String[] dude1=new String[] {"nitin","avi","aman","rahul","pattrick","minkle","manmohan"};

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mote.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent );
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**and my Receiver class is**

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Mote extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int icon = R.drawable.icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Hello you have to take medicine I am Nitin Sharma";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText,when );

        CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
        CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";


        //notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        final int NOTIF_ID = 1234;
        NotificationManager notofManager = (NotificationManager)context. getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.face,"NEW ACTIVITY", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Alset.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText,when );
        //Notification notification1 = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Wake up alarm", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        //notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "My Activity", "This will runs on button click", contentIntent);
        notofManager.notify(NOTIF_ID,notification);

        //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);
        //notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Context Title", "Context text", contentIntent);
        //notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    }



}
```

Comment: How to get all the remainder details associated with the specific application? That means the alarm id, text, title something like that.

Comment: For that you have to make a separate database table for storing that.

Comment: Is any other way to achieve that without using the database?

Comment: If I am using the above code for creating the alarm means, the device reboot removes all the reminder associated with the app. How can I restore all the 10 remainders after the device rebooted.?

Comment: you have set all alarms after reboot.

Comment: Yes, But I am facing problem, how and where to set all the alarms?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615373/how-to-launch-service-on-boot-complete-android read

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you want to set the alarm for 26th June and not 26th July. If so then change `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,6);` to `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,5);` because the months are zero-based. if you intend the alarm to fire on 26th july then it is expected that the alarm will fire when the date-time is 26th July 2011, 17:30

Comment: exactly,this is example of java-logic in action

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time @frieza

Answer (score 5):

1.add this in manifest file

```
 <receiver android:name=".MyAlarmReciever">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.helloandroid.alarms" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

2. make a activity

   ```
        public class AlrmActivity extends BaseAcitivity {

           TimePicker myTimePicker;
           Button buttonstartSetDialog;
           TextView textAlarmPrompt;

           TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

           final static int RQS_1 = 1;

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_alrm);

               textAlarmPrompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);

               buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
               buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
                       openTimePickerDialog(false);

                   }});


           }

           private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
               Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

               timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                       AlrmActivity.this,
                       onTimeSetListener,
                       calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                       calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                       is24r);
               timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");

               timePickerDialog.show();

           }
           TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener
                   = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){

               @Override
               public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                   Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                   Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

                   calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                   calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                   calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                   calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                   if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                       //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                       calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                   }

                   setAlarm(calSet);
               }};

           private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

               textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                       "\n\n***\n"
                               + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                               + "***\n");

               Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyAlarmReciever.class);
               PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
               AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
               alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

           }

       }
   ```

3 . xml file  include

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startSetDialog"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set Target Time"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alarmprompt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

4 .make alarm manager class

```
    public class MyAlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

        Vibrator v;
        Context ct;
        String  title;


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ct=context;

            Log.e("onReceive", "ladskjflsakjdflskjdflskjdfslkjdflasdf");
            Toast.makeText(context, "OnReceive alarm test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            v=(Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(3000);

            int badgeCount = 1;
           // ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, badgeCount);

            ShortcutBadger.removeCount(context);

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            try{
                  title = intent.getExtras().get("title").toString();
                 // title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
                Toast.makeText(context, title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    //        if (!Utlis.checkNetworkConnection(context)) {
    //
    //            Notification(context, "Wifi Connection off");
    //
    //        } else {
                Notification(context, "Please  pray for this prayer ");

    //        }

        }


        public void Notification(Context context, String message) {
            // Set Notification Title
            String strtitle = "iPray  Prayer Reminder";
            // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, PrayerForOtherActivity.class);
            // Send data to NotificationView Class
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("text", title);
            // Open NotificationView.java Activity
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //        NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.app_icon, "Previous", pIntent).build();
            // Create Notification using NotificationCompat.Builder
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context)
                    // Set Icon
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                    // Set Ticker Message
                    .setTicker(message)
                    // Set Title
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    // Set Text
                    .setContentText(message)
                    // Add an Action Button below Notification
                    // Set PendingIntent into Notification
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    // Dismiss Notification
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            // Create Notification Manager
            NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // Build Notification with Notification Manager
            notificationmanager.notify(38, builder.build());

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the receiver in your manifest file?
Something like this

```
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name=".Mote"></receiver>
```

Comment: Yes, but `android:process=":remote"` is not 100% necessary.

Comment: Yeah dude, android:process tag is only for running Services and Receivers in a separate process from your own app.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help

```
@Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

                calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                    //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                    calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                }

                setAlarm(calSet);
            }};

        private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

            textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                    "\n\n***\n"
                    + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                    + "***\n");

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    //      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
```

Comment: How to get all the remainder details associated with the specific application? That means the alarm id, text, title something like that.