# How to set alarm

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set Alarm in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520403/how-to-set-alarm-in-android)

I am new to android development. I don't even Know basics for setting the alarm. So please anyone help me.

Comment: Not downvoting. But you should put some efforts in your question.

Comment: yep dont be discouraged too :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). See an example [here (API demoes)](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmController.html).