# Alerting the user of a TO-DO task whos alert date and time is stored in the db

Tags: java, android

I am very new to android and I am developing this app which allows users to have a TO-DO list where they can add a task and associate a date and time as to when the task has to be carried out.I need to store the date, time and the task on SQLlite DB and need to cause an alarm when the time is due for the alarm.But I am not able to figure out a proper approach for this.
Help appriciated.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please post your code and specify the exact issue you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for database connectivity.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

this can be used to start ur service in the future. thus use alarms.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

also for the working of an alarm, take a look at this.
[How to set Alarm in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520403/how-to-set-alarm-in-android)

you can arrange the data in the database according to the time when alarm is meant to go off.
and always keep a check on the topmost row of the database and let the alarm go when the time has come. then move to the next row.

i hope this helped.