# how to get alarm on specific time and date in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

i want to set alarm on specific time and specific Date and get Alart on that time.
for example :=

```
alarm set on 5:30 pm and 26/09/2012
```

so how to set programically alarm In android

Comment: are you talking about the alarmmanager to start an Intent or do you want to register an Alarm in the Android Device AlarmClock Application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be needing a receiver to do that.
Entire process can be explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520403/how-to-set-alarm-in-android)

Also you can see [Here](http://blog.mikesir87.io/2013/04/android-creating-an-alarm-with-alarmmanager/) and [Here](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129)

Hope it is all that you want.

Comment: when i want to set alarm on Monday and today is Wednesday so how to set alarm in this situation ..thank in Advance

Comment: Set:Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);

Comment: Refer the Calendar class for more details..:http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html