# How to launch service on boot complete android?

Tags: android, service, boot, application-restart

I've read some tutorial on launch service on boot.
What I've done is:

In manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
</uses-permission>

<receiver android:name="my.package.ServiceStartup" >
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

CODE:

```
public class ServiceStartup extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyActivity.class);
               dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
           }
        }, 10000);
    }
}
```

In this way, if i reboot my device and go to setting in active applications, my service is not launched. What can I do? Where I make error? thanks!!

Comment: @jackTurkey u got any solution becuse same issu i am facing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to start activity or service. In case of service, you will have to call `startService()`. Like:

`getApplication().startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));`

Comment: i want to start service "ServiceStartup" that after 10 seconds launch an activity....

Comment: I assume you are not doing much i during those 10 seconds. Not getting a user input atleast. You may want to call `Thread.sleep(10000)` and then start the activity. Or else in you onCreate() of activity you will have to wait for 10seconds and then start it there.

Comment: ok.. but i don't think the problem was there cause in my active application ( on settings ) i don't see my service running

Comment: because you have not started it yet. You only started the activity. If you want more insight, please paste your actvity code, where you are starting the activity.

Comment: witch service i have to start in postDelayed? :)

Comment: the service you want to start. To make sure, are you confused between a service and an activity?

Comment: i'm not confused.. i want to start activity from my boot service.. u say me to start a service in postdelayed not activity

Answer (score 1):

Did you run your app? Refer to [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

> If you application is installed on the SD card, then it is not available after the android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED event. Register yourself in this case for the android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE event.

---

> Also note that as of Android 3.0 the user needs to have started the application at least once before your application can receive android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED events.