# Make Custom Android Alarm for reminder

Tags: android

i am making medicine reminder app,In that app i have included facility of adding a reminder about doctor's appointment. In my application user is allowed to set his/her own date and time and on that date and time alarm should triggered.. please help me.. and i have take reference from this thread.. 
    [How to set Alarm in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520403/how-to-set-alarm-in-android)

Comment: i have tried alarm manager,pending intent and everything but yet not get the desired result..

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

Comment: http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/

Answer (score 6):

Use the following steps.

**For reminder in calendar:**

1.Create a event as:

```
// get calendar
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();     
Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "events");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

// event insert
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("calendar_id", 1);
values.put("title", "Reminder Title");
values.put("allDay", 0);
values.put("dtstart", cal.getTimeInMillis() + 11*60*1000); // event starts at 11     minutes from now
values.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000); // ends 60 minutes from now
values.put("description", "Reminder description");
values.put("visibility", 0);
values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
```

2.Then create reminder and set it useing code as:

```
// reminder insert
Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "reminders");
values = new ContentValues();
values.put( "event_id", Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
values.put( "method", 1 );
values.put( "minutes", 10 );
cr.insert( REMINDERS_URI, values );
```

3.Set permissions as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

**For Alarm only ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20130724094711/http://justcallmebrian.com/2010/04/27/using-alarmmanager-to-schedule-activities-on-android/)):**

> 1.Create a broadcast receiver as:
>
> ```
> public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
>
>     @Override
>     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>         try {
>             Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
>             String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
>             Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> 2.Set permission:
>
> ```
> <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
> ```
>
> 3.Set up event:
>
> ```
> // get a Calendar object with current time
> Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
> // add 5 minutes to the calendar object
> cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
> Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
> intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "O'Doyle Rules!");
> // In reality, you would want to have a static variable for the request code instead of 192837
> PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intent,    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>
> // Get the AlarmManager service
> AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
> am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
> ```
>
> 4.Activity from broadcast receiver:
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>     try {
>         Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
>         String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
>  
>         Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
>         newIntent.putExtra("alarm_message", message);
>         newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
>         context.startActivity(newIntent);
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Modify the code as needed.