# How to play alarm on specified time in android?

Tags: android, timer, alarmmanager, alarm

I'm a beginner to android development.

I'm developing an app that need to play alarm exactly from 8 hrs from the time which am clicking a button.

I've created a line which gets the current time but am stuck to calculate 8 hrs from current time and play the alarm tone.

Here's my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ToggleButton; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public ToggleButton tgb1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tgb1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

        tgb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


        if (tgb1.getText().toString().equals("Click to Turn Off"))
        {

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
            String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            c.add(Calendar.HOUR,8);
```

But I don't know to proceed further from here. Kindly help me in calculating 8 hrs from current time and play alarm tone.

Waiting for your kind response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use AlarmManager to run your code at a later time. According to **Android documentation**

> The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running.

Since you already have the Calendar object c

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

where pendingIntent can have a service Class invoked which plays the audio tone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520403/how-to-set-alarm-in-android) can help you too. Always add (c.Add) minutes/hours/days to the Calendar instance before formatting and assigning value to String because now your "strDate" equals to the actual time without 8 hours added later.

Comment: Can you not use link-only answers? I know those are android docs and SO questions, but what if the location of the docs moved? What if the question somehow gets deleted? This answer would become invalid. Adding some explanation can help the answer out.